# YR8001 RFID reader

Tags: wireless-networking, arduino

I am doing a project on passive RFID system using YR8001 RFID reader. I am beginner and don't know much about it. After reading various articles and blogs I got to know that most readers allow the user to use RS232 (YR 8001 also does). RS232 and TTL works on two different voltage levels, and if someone wants to connect the reader to computer via a microcontroller you need a RS232 -TTL convertor (I am using MAX232 for that).

The site from which I have ordered the part gives with the product a software that helps you interact with the reader, but it does not give any option to send the output to microcontroller. My need is to read the RFID tag and if it does it should output to the microcontroller. Therefore I am trying to make my own program using Arduino.

To check if my reader is connected to my PC I am using coolTerm (a serial communication software). While I can successfully connect it by clicking on connect button in the coolTerm, I am not sure if it is actually connecting since I can not see anything on the Serial Monitor screen and as per my understanding after reading various blogs, the reader should send some notification stating yes your computer is connected to the reader and they can both now communicate.

Any leads on what should I do would be of great help to me since I am stuck and I can't think of how to proceed now.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example that I was working some months ago. I think it works fine. The program resets the antena, then sets the working antenna and then works as a real time inventory. If you know some about arduino you can read in the code. (It has some spanish comments, 'cause I am in Mexico)

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>

File myFile;

byte reset_Message[] = {0xA0, 0x03, 0x01, 0x70, 0xEC };
byte set_WorkingAntenna[] = {0xA0, 0x04, 0x01, 0x74, 0x00, 0xE7 };
byte real_TimeInventory[] = {0xA0, 0x04, 0x01, 0x89, 0x01, 0xD1 };

int cont = 0;
int contSD = 1;
byte tag_ID[21];
String tag_IDInt="";

unsigned long previousMillis = 0;        // will store last time LED was updated

// constants won't change :
const long interval = 100;           // interval at which to blink (milliseconds)

boolean found = false;

void setup() {
  // initialize both serial ports:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }
  Serial2.begin(115200);
  Serial.print("Inicializando Memoria SD...");
  if (!SD.begin(4)) {
    Serial.println("Inicializacion Fallida!");
    return;
  }
  Serial.println("Inicializacion Correcta.");
  delay(100);
  Serial2.write(reset_Message, sizeof(reset_Message));
  delay(500);
  Serial2.write(set_WorkingAntenna, sizeof(set_WorkingAntenna));
  delay(50);
  Serial2.write(real_TimeInventory, sizeof(real_TimeInventory));  
  tag_IDInt.reserve(200);
}

void loop() {
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
    previousMillis = currentMillis;
    Serial2.write(set_WorkingAntenna, sizeof(set_WorkingAntenna));
    delay(50);
    Serial2.write(real_TimeInventory, sizeof(real_TimeInventory));
  }

  // read from port 2, send to port 0:
  if (Serial2.available()) {
    byte inByte = (byte)Serial2.read();
    tag_ID [cont] = inByte;
    //Serial.write(inByte);
    cont++;
    if (cont == 6 && tag_ID[3] == 116){ cont = 0;}
    if (cont == 12 && tag_ID[4] == 0 ){ cont = 0;}
    if (cont == 21){
      for (int i=7; i<19; i++){
        tag_IDInt += String(tag_ID[i],HEX);
        //Serial.print(tag_ID[i], HEX);
        //Serial.print(" ");
      }
      tag_IDInt += (char)'\r';
      Serial.print("Tu ID es: ");
      Serial.print(tag_IDInt);
      if (lookForID(tag_IDInt)){
        Serial.println(", Acceso Permitido");
      }else{
        Serial.println(", Acceso Denegado");
      }
      found = false;
      tag_IDInt = "";
      cont = 0;
    }
  }
}

boolean lookForID(String read_ID){
  // open the file. note that only one file can be open at a time,
  // so you have to close this one before opening another.
  myFile = SD.open("TAGIDS.csv", FILE_WRITE);

  // re-open the file for reading:
  myFile = SD.open("TAGIDS.csv");
  if (myFile) {
    // read from the file until there's nothing else in it:
    while (myFile.available() && !found) {
      String line = myFile.readStringUntil('\n'); 
      if (line == read_ID){  
        //Serial.print(" Found in Line ");
        //Serial.print(contSD);
        found = true;
        contSD = 1;
        return true;
      }
      else
        contSD++;
    }
    // close the file:
    myFile.close();
    if(!found){
      contSD = 1;
      return false;
    }
  } else {
    // if the file didn't open, print an error:
    Serial.println("Error Abriendo TAGIDS.csv");
  }
}
```